# How to limit the number of search results per directory

Tags: grep, find, search

How to limit the number of search results per folder, for example:

With this command:

```
grep --include=*.php -Ril '<?' '/var/www/'
```

I get the following:

```
/var/www/test.php
/var/www/test1.php
/var/www/phpinfo1.php
/var/www/phpinfoo.php
/var/www/phpinfooo.php
/var/www/1/php.php
/var/www/1/php3.php
/var/www/1/index.php
/var/www/1/indexed.php
/var/www/1/indexin.php
/var/www/test/tester.php
/var/www/test/info.php
/var/www/test/inform.php
/var/www/test/conf.php
```

And I need only 3 results per folder, and therefore it is:

```
/var/www/test.php
/var/www/test1.php
/var/www/phpinfo1.php
/var/www/1/php.php
/var/www/1/php3.php
/var/www/1/index.php
/var/www/test/tester.php
/var/www/test/info.php
/var/www/test/inform.php
```

Comment: What about `grep`'s `-m` option ? or `-c`?

Answer (score 2):

The recursive grep will scan the entire tree and not care about directory structure.  You need to traverse the structure and grep each directory individually.

```
find /var/www -type d -print | while read dirname; do grep -sil '<?' "$dirname"/*.php | head -3; done
```

The `grep -s` will handle conditions where there are no php files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
for DIR in $( find ./test -mindepth 1 -type d ); do
    find "$DIR" -type f | grep "\.php" | head -n3
done
```

`find ./test -mindepth 1 -type d` lists all the directories in the `test` directory excluding the parent.

`find "$DIR"` lists the full path in each directory and then greps for the php extension and lists three with head.

```
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir dir{test,1,anotherdir} && touch dir{test,1,anotherdir}/file{a,b,c,d,e,f}.php
cd ..
```

Output:

```
./test/dirtest/filed.php
./test/dirtest/filec.php
./test/dirtest/filee.php
./test/dir1/filed.php
./test/dir1/filec.php
./test/dir1/filee.php
./test/diranotherdir/filed.php
./test/diranotherdir/filec.php
./test/diranotherdir/filee.php
```